# Difference between conditions in the same or separated where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A small and simple question, I have these 2 where example clauses:

```
Product.where("name = ? AND is_done = ?", "test",false)

Product.where(name:"test").where(is_done:false)
```

I would rather use the second one because its more readable and easier to add more where if I want, now my question is: Which one is faster, more secure and/or more recommended?

Thanks for yout answers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equally secure since you've escaped the first one properly and the second is escaped by Rails.  You can run a test in your console using "benchmark" to see the difference in speed. In your console try:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.measure do
    Product.where("name = ? AND is_done = ?", "test",false)
end
```

Then compare to

```
Benchmark.measure do
  Product.where(name:"test").where(is_done:false)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same query.  It is mostly a matter of preference.

An easy way to see this is to do this in the development Rails environment, as the generated SQL query will be written to the development log.  So you can actually see how a change in Ruby syntax changes (or does not change) the actual SQL query that gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are SQL Injection secure, there are some subtle differences that might make a small difference in performance/flexibility.
The first one is going to sanitize the params and place them into the string whilst the other is going to use Arel to create the query. However the second function is could be rewritten to be more efficient:

```
Product.where(name:"test", is_done:false)
```

Since there's a call to the function instead of two.

Another difference is that the last one only can be used for ANDs but not ORs, which in case of being needed you have to pass the string, or use the new `.or` operator.

```
Product.where("name = ? OR is_done = ?", "test",false)

Post.where('id = 1').or(Post.where('id = 2'))
```